# Why the DB cannot get the data sent by post method?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning PHP OOP and I have a problem. This is a really beginner code, I am practicing to my exam but I'm stuck so I would need some help.
I use CodeIgniter, the database library is filled and autoloaded.

I have a form: user has to fill the name, email and phone fields. A controller gets it, give it to the model which should insert the data to the database but I get an error message: "Column 'trainedName' cannot be null" so I guess it doesn't get the data in the first place.

view (simplified):

```
<form action="index.php/aboutme/calling" method="POST" enctype="text/plain">
  <input class="callback" type="text" name="nev" placeholder="Neved:" required>
  <input class="callback" type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail címed:"  required>
  <input class="callback" type="tel" name="telszam" placeholder="Telefonszámod (36201234567):"  required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

controller:

```
class Aboutme extends CI_Controller {
public function calling() {
            $datas=array();
            
            $trained = new Callback();
            $trained->addTrained($datas);

            $this->load->view('aboutme');
    }
```

model:

```
class Callback extends CI_Model {

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function addTrained(){

        $na = $this->input->post('nev');
        $em = $this->input->post('email');
        $ph = $this->input->post('telszam');

        $datas = array(
            'trainedName' => $na, 
            'email' => $em, 
            'phone' => $ph
        );   

        $this->db->insert('trained', $datas);
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said `enctype="text/plain"`. This causes the form to submit data in a form that is more readable to humans but which *cannot* be reliably interpreted by machines. PHP won't parse that format for you. Don't do that.